# Login script works on WinXP but not on Win7

Tags: windows, vbscript, internet-explorer-8, wsh

I have a script which logs in to a website. It works perfectly on IE 8 on Windows XP, but when I try the same script on Windows 7 with IE8 it doesn't work.

Can somebody fix this issue?

```
WScript.Quit Main
Function Main
 Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
 IE.Visible = True
 IE.Navigate "URL"
 Wait IE
 IE.Document.form.[username].value = "" 'username
 IE.Document.form.[password].value = "" 'Password
 IE.Document.form.Submit()    
End Function   
Sub Wait(IE)    
 Do  
  WScript.Sleep 500       
 Loop While IE.ReadyState <> 4 OR IE.Busy
End SUb
Sub IE_OnQuit
 On Error Resume Next
 WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
 WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: How have you realised that it doesn't work? Whatever, this is not even JavaScript code.

Comment: The script open the url in IE and doesnt put the login credentials. In IE, i dont see any error in particular.

Comment: I do get this as an error sometimes Message: Unterminated string constant or Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: This might be a permissions/security issue. If you have access to both browsers (the one on XP that works as well as the one on Win7 that doesn't), compare the settings under Tools->Options->Advanced.